# Decent backup tool for App Engine (Java)? With incremental backups

Tags: google-app-engine, backup

There's the BulkLoader which is nice but lacks many features of any normal backup tool, as I can see, like incremental backups.
Another issue with this tool is that it doesn't always work properly - my app has ~2GB.
Bottom line - unreliable.

So, is there any good tool out there with incremental backups or should I implement on my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this tool: [datastorebackup.com](http://www.datastorebackup.com/)

Seems to be very good (tested a bit) - did anyone use it on a large site?